# TLSv1 handshake failure

Tags: java, windows, https, ssl

(Disclaimer: I am by no stretch of the imagination a security expert nor a windows expert for that matter)

Setup:

- server on our end: java 1.6 (already added bouncycastle to the security file) on windows 2003 server
- third party client: windows 2008 server with biztalk
- all renegotiation system properties introduced due to the renegotiation attack are "enabled" on the server side (not safe I know)

Ideally we want to fix this at our end but it is possible to propose a fix to the client if necessary.

The client server has to connect to our server over a HTTPS connection but it always fails, wireshark shows the following conversation:

```
> TLSv1: Client Hello
< TLSv1: Alert (21): Unexpected Message
```

As per the RFC (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) the alert(21) refers to a failed decryption and from what I can see in wireshark, none of the ciphers proposed by the client are actually supported by JRE 1.6 (as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SupportedCipherSuites)
In an effort to reproduce the error to be able to examine it closer, I tested with some other software:

- wfetch on windows xp with "https" selected will perform the initial client handshake in SSLv2, the server will switch to TLSv1 to answer, this works
- wfetch on windows xp with configured to use "TLSv1" for the initial handshake will fail in the same way as the biztalk server
- wfetch on windows 2008 with configured "https" will use "TLSv1" for the initial handshake and fail in the same way as the biztalk server
- IE (on windows xp) will initially try a TLSv1 handshake with the same failed result but immediately tries again using SSLv3 which works
  (at this point I figure all microsoft software uses a central configuration available at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel)
- firefox uses SSLv3 for the entire conversation, so no problem there
- OpenSSL performs an initial handshake in SSLv2, and the server switches to TLSv1 when it answers, no problem there
- OpenSSL can be forced to do the initial handshake in TLSv1 as well, it offers a list of 27 ciphers (as opposed to the 11 ciphers proposed by windows-based software) and can connect without a problem

To my untrained eye this reinforces the idea that an incompatible cipher proposition is the root cause where windows only supports cipher suites that are not supported by JVM (for TLSv1).
I have installed bouncy castle as an additional provider in the java.security file to no avail.
I have searched high and low and only found a reference that maybe websphere supports the windows ciphers for TLSv1 but no way of downloading a standalone provider to test it.
JRE 1.7 is not supported by the software we run on our JVM, so upgrading is not an option (perhaps the security provider can be downgraded safely? I haven't found a download for it yet though)
I have found no way to add a cipher to windows short of writing c++ code (I've played around with the above mentioned registry settings without effect).

So in conclusion I wonder if one of the following things would fix it and how they should be accomplished:

- add a provider to the jvm that can work with the ciphers for TLSv1 that are proposed by windows
- somehow force the client to do the initial handshake in SSLv3 (preferably not SSLv2) or at least retry if the TLSv1 handshake fails
- somehow add a JVM-supported cipher for TLSv1 to the client windows

Any other solutions are of course also appreciated.

**EDIT**

The Java version is `Java version (64 bit): 1.6.0_19-b04`.

The list of proposed ciphers is:

- TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
- TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA
- TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
- TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
- TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
- TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA

The unlimited strength cryptography policy files are installed. I have tried to set `javax.net.debug=all` and started the server from the console, no additional output appeared. I have set `sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true` to no avail.

**EDIT 2**

It turns out the software we are using uses a custom stack for HTTPs instead of the default. A fix was issued which seems to solve the problem though I don't know exactly which part of the TLS request triggered the error (seeing as most TLSv1 handshakes did succeed).

Thanks for the feedback, it has been an interesting if futile search. Live and learn.

Comment: Can you show a list of ciphers that the client is proposing?

Comment: What is the full Java version you are using? Also: do you have the Unlimited Strength Cryptography policy files installed in the Java Runtime?

Comment: (You shouldn't need to add the BouncyCastle provider in general.) If this application uses `HttpsUrlConnection`, try to set this system property: `https.protocols=SSLv3,TLS`. Just to try a few other things: `sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true` (not recommended, just in case...). It would also be useful to see if there are more details when turning debugging on: `javax.net.debug=all` or a least `javax.net.debug=handshake`.

Comment: This is the list of ciphers the windows client propose?  I believe both RC2, RC4 and DES are considered too weak to use in new applications, this was a strange list.  The RFC seems to define that a compliant application must implement TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA which is in neither the proposed list or the java list.

Comment: What's your server running? Is it in a servlet container (e.g. Apache Tomcat)? Just to investigate the cipher suites, have you tried to play with ciphers and SSL/TLS versions in Firefox? (`about:config` in the location bar, then toggle `security.enable_tls`/`enable_ssl`. It might be worth trying to enable/disable specific cipher suites (see `security.ssl3.*` options). (Btw, my comment about `https.protocols` was useless since you're on the server side, sorry.)  @RolfRander: it's called `SSL_...` in the Java list, this prefix is just a convention for legacy, the underlying code is the same.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (after your 2nd edit), if you can would you mind giving us more details regarding which custom HTTPS stack it is (presumably a custom SSL/TLS stack)? Is it 100% custom or based on a known library?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know if the custom stack is based on a known library nor how much they have customized.

Comment: @user1109519 Can we get this question resolved? It shows up with a lot of votes but is clearly dead. You can submit your own "EDIT 2" as the answer and then accept it so it will no longer show up in the queries as "unanswered and high vote count".

Comment: Also, we could all vote to delete it since the user never filled out their user info and so they are obviously not necessarily 'actual' member of Stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the software we are using uses a custom stack for HTTPs instead of the default. A fix was issued which seems to solve the problem though I don't know exactly which part of the TLS request triggered the error (seeing as most TLSv1 handshakes did succeed).

Thanks for the feedback, it has been an interesting if futile search. Live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

You could read my article on [detecting cipher strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887030/how-can-i-find-verify-the-encryption-strength-of-my-jdk-security-providers/10890397#10890397) (just to make sure you installed the jce ciphers correctly) .   In your question you say you installed unlimited ciphers but then you reference 128 and 40-bit keys.  So, I am confused by what you have.  Also, could you check the cipher strength on the SSL cert you are trying to connect to and let us know what it is and what the algorithm is?  Also, make sure your policy file for JDK has the proper rights to allow unlimited strength.

Finally, can you connect to a "known good" SSL site to verify your client handshakes correctly?  (Gmail web for example)

Comment: Except for a few very rare exceptions, people who want to use SSL/TLS do it because they want to establish a secure connection between the client and the server. Suggesting to use a trust manager that will allow anything and a hostname verifier that accepts anything too just makes all that useless. Please stop suggesting these "workarounds". Sure they get rid of the warnings, but they also make MITM attacks possible.

Comment: Sorry, the question seems to have changed quite a bit since I answered it.  My answer is probably no longer relevant.